# Smokeping unknown variable 'menu'

Tags: linux, docker

I am trying to set up smokeping in a container. It is running on alpine. I get the following error however: ERROR: /config/Probes, line 7: unknown variable 'menu'

Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

```
*** Probes ***



+ FPing



binary = /usr/sbin/fping

menu = Top

title = Ping
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was following this guide. I was supposed to place the second part in the targets file not in the probes file.

https://github.com/alecs/smokeping-plugins/blob/master/SqlLatency.README